# Do other cultures' foods have anything like ramen eggs?

Tags: eggs, hard-boiled-eggs

One of my favourite parts of making ramen is *ajitsuke tamago* – a soft-boiled egg marinated in soy sauce, *mirin*, and *sake*.

Marinating a boiled egg to impart flavour seems like a simple idea, but I'm not aware of any other dishes like it. Is this something that's been done in other culinary traditions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ajitsuke tamago are likely a culinary descendant of lu dan, [Chinese soy sauce marinated eggs](https://www.chinasichuanfood.com/soy-sauce-eggs/). Lu dan are also frequently added to soups, and can be hard or medium boiled.

As a very old Asian food, they exist in other Asian cuisines as well, including [Korean](https://tiffycooks.com/korean-marinated-eggs-mayak-gyeran-easy/) and [Filipino](https://silkroadrecipes.com/filipino-marinated-eggs-adobo-eggs/).

What's interesting is the lack of marinated, but not pickled, egg recipes from non-Asian cultures.  Every country in Europe has some form of pickled eggs, but savory marinated eggs doesn't seem to be something that Europeans discovered before trade with China.

Comment: [before at least 2000 years ago…](https://iltaodilao-blogspot-com.translate.goog/2011/02/il-made-in-china-impazzava-roma-2000.html?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=it&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps not having really the same sense of gastronomic style or delicacy…

In the UK, pickled eggs used to be a staple; eat them on their own, with a beer or with takeaway fish & chips.

[image]

Traditional ones in the UK were in brown or white vinegar with spices. Variants are many, with highly coloured extras added for variety.

[image]
From [Simply Recipes](https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/pickled_eggs/)

Comment: Picked eggs were also popular bar snacks in Brasil in the past. The ones I've seen myself looked like they've been floating in vinegar since the 50's...

Answer (score 7):

Lots of East Asian culinary traditions have eggs simmered in flavourings, like tea eggs and iron eggs. And in Germany and subsequently the US there’s a tradition of pickling hard-cooked eggs in brine. And there are stews around the world including (and, I suppose, incidentally flavouring) hard-cooked eggs, of course. But I’m not aware of any other traditions of marinating soft-boiled eggs. (And I doubt any exist. Japan is *precise* about eggs, in a way virtually no other culture is.)

Comment: Tea eggs sound very interesting, I think I'll have to give them a try.